# Unfamiliar function declaration syntax in c#

Tags: c#, syntax

I am learning c# and have come across an unfamiliar syntax for calling a function:

```
    static void Main() => Foo(); // this is unfamiliar
    static void Foo 
       (
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = null, 
        [CallerFilePath] string filePath = null,
        [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0
       ) {
            Console.WriteLine (memberName);
            Console.WriteLine (filePath);
            Console.WriteLine (lineNumber);
    }
```

Can you tell me the right google search keywords? I will look it up on my own, no need to explain anything.

Comment: It is a lambda expression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression-bodied members.

> Expression body definitions let you provide a member's implementation in a very concise, readable form. You can use an expression body definition whenever the logic for any supported member, such as a method or property, consists of a single expression. An expression body definition has the following general syntax:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members